# 'kivy.graphics.context_instructions.BindTexture' object has no attribute 'children'

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm using a multiline TextField on kivy and everything works fine until type multiple lines and I press anywhere on the UI. In the python code part, I'm not touching anything that has to do with text field so I don't think there's a problem from there. If the kv file bellow isn't enough I'll be more than happy to provide more information.

Thanks!

Here is my main.kv code:

```
<HomeScreen>:    
    name: "home"

    GridLayout:
        name: "main_grid"
        id: maingrid
        cols: 1

        MDToolbar:
            title: app.title
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            background_palette: "Primary"
            elevation: 10
            right_action_items: [['play', app.execute]]




        MDLabel:
            text: "Code:"
            size_hint: None, pt(.1)


        MDSeparator:

        MDTextFieldRect:
            id: code_field
            multiline: True
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
            hint_text: "Enter your code here!"
            background_color: (0,0,0,0)

        MDLabel:
            text: "Result:"
            size_hint: None, pt(.1)

        MDSeparator:

        MDTextFieldRect:
            id: result_field
            multiline: True
            readonly: True
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
            background_color: (0,0,0,0)
            color: "accent"
```

The full log in case is needed:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 166, in <module>
     RextesterApp().run()
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 826, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 502, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 403, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 289, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 340, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 325, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 231, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1360, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1376, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py", line 1191, in on_touch_down
     return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 460, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 288, in on_touch_down
     ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 460, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 460, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/textinput.py", line 1340, in on_touch_down
     if super(TextInput, self).on_touch_down(touch):
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/focus.py", line 441, in on_touch_down
     self.focus = True
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 483, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 524, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 579, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/focus.py", line 384, in _on_focus
     self._bind_keyboard()
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/focus.py", line 399, in _bind_keyboard
     self._ensure_keyboard()
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/focus.py", line 393, in _ensure_keyboard
     self._keyboard_released, self, input_type=self.input_type)
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 445, in request_keyboard
     callback, target, input_type)
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1902, in request_keyboard
     self.release_keyboard(target)
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 451, in release_keyboard
     super(WindowPygame, self).release_keyboard(*largs)
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1980, in release_keyboard
     callback()
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/focus.py", line 433, in _keyboard_released
     self.focus = False
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 483, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 524, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 579, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1096, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/home/alexandrumarcel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "<string>", line 89, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kivymd/textfields.py", line 330, in anim_rect
     instance_line = root_canvas.children[2]
 AttributeError: 'kivy.graphics.context_instructions.BindTexture' object has no attribute 'children'
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in KivyMD. How much can you take out of your app before the error goes away, what is a truly minimal example of it happening?

Comment: @inclement Almost all of the app it seems. This is all I have left and the error is still there: https://del.dog/ivigikegef.py EDIT: The error stop raising when I removed the GridLayout import

Comment: It happens as soon as I click anywhere on press esc

Comment: Please post your reduced minimal example.

Comment: @NitanAlexandruMarcel: I am not able to recreate the problem. Could you please provide step by step for recreating the problem. Which version of KivyMD are you running? What is your OS (Mac OS, Ubuntu, Kali, etc.), Python version, and Kivy version?

Comment: @ikolim I completely forgot about this question. The problem has been fixed yesterday morning by the kivymd developer. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I made an issue on GitHub at the time I posted this question and the problem has been fixed by the developer of kivymd